# Adding Style to Columns in LWC Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to style the individual columns in my lwc datatable.  I found some examples but for some reason, I can't get a custom css to work.  I'm thinking I have a syntax error somewhere.  Here is my column:

```
{ label: 'Package', fieldName: 'Package_Code__c', type: 'text', sortable: "true", fixedWidth: 100, cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'mydates' }}}
```

And here is my css:

```
 .mydates {
    background : blue;
    color : white;
 }
```

I found an example using a class that is slds and when I use the below, it formats the field.  Just not when I use my custom style.

```
 cellAttributes: {
        class: 'slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture slds-border_left',
        iconName: { fieldName: 'myIcon' },
        iconPosition: { fieldName: 'myIconPosition' },
        alignment: 'right',
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Fred

Comment: ```THIS``` keyword is used in CSS for aura component, in LWC, you do not need to use it.

Comment: Thanks for responding Klecool!  Unfortunately, removing THIS did not fix the problem.  thanks!